# API front-end architecture

Tags: python, django, architecture, celery

I want to build a web site that is a front-end for an API. Basically, the front-end takes some user input and uses that to query the API and retrieve results. When the results are retrieved, they are displayed. This is all done asynchronously.

My questions are:

1. Do I use something like Celery to handle the API querying in the background?
2. Assuming I use AJAX (which I will), do I have different URLs for handling user input and retrieval of the query results?
3. Do I use something like long polling to get and display the results with JavaScript?
4. Considering that the retrieved results can be further filtered, I'm considering using memcached as a storage. Is this appropriate?

If there's anything I've missed, or if there's a better approach, I'd be glad to hear about it.

Edit: I realized that I explained the requirements in a wrong way, so I'll try to reword.
Basically, my website is based on an API I have no control over. So, there's the 3rd-party API, my application with Django in the back-end and the front-end with JavaScript, CSS and HTML.

This is the reason why I introduced Celery into the mix. The flow of the application, in my mind, is like this. The user enters the required information on my web page and, when the user submits the data, that is sent to my back-end asynchronously. Now, Celery is used to send a request to the 3rd-party API and retrieve data. Meanwhile, my front-end keeps polling my back-end for the data and starts displaying it as it receives it.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing some points here. By your requirements I assume that you want to build a frontend (html + javascript) that queries a (RESTful) API, which will simply be a server that "speaks" HTTP.

So, your API querying has to do with your server, that is, with Django on Apache or with Tornado or.. Celery cannot "handle" your queries, but it can be useful for background tasks.

On the client-side, your AJAX calls shall trigger some server-side views that are mapped to some URLS. How you will define them is up to you. Have a look at some popular APIs ( twitter ) to see how they are structured.

Long-polling has to do with your "business" logic, and it defines a way on how to present data  to the client, later.

Also, caching has to do with your server-side performance, and you are encouraged to use something like memcached or redis.

EDIT (for the edit): There is nothing wrong with your approach. Celery is the right tool to fetch data from an external API, then save the results to a database and of course use some caching. Then do some polling from the client to get the results. But, there exists a more optimal, non-blocking, elegant way of doing the same. You can use Tornado to fetch data from the external API, and when those data are ready, send them to the client. No Celery, no long-polling. A great code snippet [here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/gen.html).

Comment: Your answer made me realize that I explained my problem incorrectly. I've updated my explanation (hopefully it's clearer).